# No credit card, but debit with vpay in Sweden

Tags: money, sweden

I'm doing a round-trip right now and would like to visit Sweden, but I'm wondering how far I would get with just a normal debit card with v-pay.

Are there ATMs in smaller towns? (Along Inlandsbanan)

Is cash still accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You should be fine with a debit card with v-pay, but make sure you have some backup cash.

> Is cash still accepted?

It is accepted in most places. However, merchants are allowed to refuse you to pay with cash, see e.g. [Merchants are allowed to refuse cash payments (text in Swedish)](https://www.sydsvenskan.se/2017-08-08/okning-av-rattanmalningar-i-malmo-invasion-i-herrgarden-uppror). In this case, your v-pay card should work fine.

**ATM's in smaller towns?**

Generally, there's at least one ATM in every smaller town. You can search for "bankomat [town]" or "uttagsautomat [town]".

**ATM's along Inlandsbanan?**

I just searched for "bankomat [town]", for a few towns along the way, and there are at least ATM's in the following towns (Inlandsbanan, south to north):

- Mora
- Sveg
- Östersund
- Vilhemina
- Arvidsjaur

So you should have no problems finding an ATM along the way (note that there is most likely ATM's in other towns you'll pass through as well). Note though that not all of these ATM's are close to the train station, but might require a 5-10 minute walk.

While most merchants accept cards, it's possible that there are some that only accept cash (especially if you go on an excursion from the train/town). If my memory serves me right, this was the case when I travelled on Inlandsbanan. This was 9 years ago though, so things might have changed.

With that said, I'd recommend you to exchange some cash on arrival in Sweden (or withdraw from an ATM) before you start your journey along Inlandsbanan, in case an ATM is not working (or you don't have time to go to an ATM, or something else prevents you from withdrawing money).

Enjoy your trip along Inlandsbanan!

Comment: Cash is not accepted everywhere. There are a lot of bars and smaller kiosk type places that do not accept cash. I have run into other places as well but those or the most common.

Comment: @JohanGronberg Indeed, I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Sweden is considered to be the most cashless country in the World.

Cash is rarely used and cards are very widely accepted. ATMs can usually be found near central stations and are called Bankomat.

Comment: _Bankomat_ is a brand name. The generic word for ATM is _uttagsautomat_.